# SwiftUI - How to vertically align a Text view with another Text view to make something similar to a Table with proper alignment?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I basically need to make a table similar to this in SwiftUI:

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, Im having a hard time aligning the fields to their corresponding columns, as in "John" should be exactly centered to "Name" and "EUR" should be centered to "Currency", etc. As you can see on the code, Im currently eye-balling it with the stacks spacing parameter, but thats just plain awful and doesnt even work on all devices plus data is dynamic and comes from an API call so it just wont work. How can I align this on SwiftUI? I need to support iOS 13.

Current code:

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                TitleBackground()
                Text("Clients")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("Name")
                Text("Balance")
                Text("Currency")
                Spacer()
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4783782363, green: 0.4784628153, blue: 0.4783664346, alpha: 1)))
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            .padding(12)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9332349896, green: 0.9333916306, blue: 0.9332130551, alpha: 1)))
            RowView()
            RowView()
            RowView()
            RowView()
        }
    }
}


struct RowView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("John")
            Text("$5300")
            Text("EUR")
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(12)
    }
}

struct TitleBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                //We only need the top corners rounded, so we embed another rectangle to the bottom.
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 15)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clarify how you want your layout to look. Will it have only the 3 "columns"? If so, do you want them to fill the width of the view? Do you want the Names to be left-aligned or centered under the Name heading? What about the Balances? If row 1 has a Balance of `50` and row 2 has a Balance of `235750` do you want those strings centered? Or right-aligned? etc...

Comment: Look like you can use `HorizontalAlignment` with `alignmentGuide` from this article 
https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>There are two ways you could solve this. First, you could use two `LazyVGrids` with the same column set up, but you would have to fix some of your sizes. The second way is</s>You can solve this with with `PreferenceKeys`.

<s>`LazyVGrid`:</s>

```
struct LazyVGridView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(100)),
        GridItem(.fixed(100)),
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 180))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                Text("Name")
                    .padding()
                Text("Balance")
                    .padding()
                Text("Currency")
                    .padding()
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4783782363, green: 0.4784628153, blue: 0.4783664346, alpha: 1)))
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9332349896, green: 0.9333916306, blue: 0.9332130551, alpha: 1)))

            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(clients) { client in
                    Text(client.name)
                        .padding()
                    Text(client.balance.description)
                        .padding()
                    Text(client.currency)
                        .padding()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`PreferenceKeys`:

```
struct PrefKeyAlignmentView: View {
    
    let clients: [ClientInfo] = [
        ClientInfo(name: "John", balance: 300, currency: "EUR"),
        ClientInfo(name: "Jennifer", balance: 53000, currency: "EUR"),
        ClientInfo(name: "Jo", balance: 30, currency: "EUR"),
        ClientInfo(name: "Jill", balance: 530000, currency: "EUR")
    ]
    
    @State private var col1Width: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var col2Width: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var col3Width: CGFloat = 110
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack() {
                Text("Name")
                    .padding()
                    // The background view takes on the size of the Text + the padding, and the GeometryReader reads that size
                    .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear.preference(
                            //This sets the preference key value with the width of the background view
                            key: Col1WidthPrefKey.self,
                            value: geometry.size.width)
                    })
                    // This set the frame to the column width variable defined above
                    .frame(width: col1Width)
                Text("Balance")
                    .padding()
                    .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear.preference(
                            key: Col2WidthPrefKey.self,
                            value: geometry.size.width)
                    })
                    .frame(width: col2Width)

                Text("Currency")
                    .padding()
                    .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear.preference(
                            key: Col3WidthPrefKey.self,
                            value: geometry.size.width)
                    })
                    .frame(width: col3Width)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            ForEach(clients) { client in
                HStack {
                    Text(client.name)
                        .padding()
                        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear.preference(
                                key: Col1WidthPrefKey.self,
                                value: geometry.size.width)
                        })
                        .frame(width: col1Width)
                    Text(client.balance.description)
                        .padding()
                        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear.preference(
                                key: Col2WidthPrefKey.self,
                                value: geometry.size.width)
                        })
                        .frame(width: col2Width)

                    Text(client.currency)
                        .padding()
                        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear.preference(
                                key: Col3WidthPrefKey.self,
                                value: geometry.size.width)
                        })
                        .frame(width: col3Width)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        //This sets the various column widths whenever a new entry as found.
        //It keeps the larger of the new item's width, or the last largest width.
        .onPreferenceChange(Col1WidthPrefKey.self) {
            col1Width = max($0,col1Width)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(Col2WidthPrefKey.self) {
            col2Width = max($0,col2Width)
       }
        .onPreferenceChange(Col3WidthPrefKey.self) {
            col3Width = max($0,col3Width)
        }
    }
}

struct ClientInfo: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let balance: Int
    let currency: String
}

private extension PrefKeyAlignmentView {
    struct Col1WidthPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
        static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                           nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
    
    struct Col2WidthPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
        static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                           nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
    
    struct Col3WidthPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
        static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                           nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think using alignmentGuides would work as you would have to handle multiple views, and alignment guides only align one set of views, and not the views internally.

<s>Both of these solutions will work.</s> The `PreferenceKeys` will automatically adapt everything, but theoretically could push past the bounds of the screen with too much information. <s>The `LazyVGrid` is more rigid, but could cause truncation/wrapping if the data is too long. I don't think you could use an adaptive layout for the `LazyVGrid` for all columns, if you have two different grids. It may be possible to mix both and set the `LazyVGrid` widths with `PreferenceKeys`, but I haven't personally tried it.</s>

DataSource for both for testing:

```
struct ClientInfo: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let balance: Int
    let currency: String
}

let clients: [ClientInfo] = [
    ClientInfo(name: "John", balance: 300, currency: "EUR"),
    ClientInfo(name: "Jennifer", balance: 53000, currency: "EUR"),
    ClientInfo(name: "Jo", balance: 30, currency: "EUR"),
    ClientInfo(name: "Jill", balance: 530000, currency: "EUR")
]
```

Edit: While working on the answer, I forgot you were restricted to iOS 13. `LazyVGrids` aren't available. I left the `LazyVGrid` answer up as you could use `if #available(os:)` if you wanted to use it for later OS's, or for someone else looking for a more current solution.

Second Edit: I was thinking about how this view could be made more reusable, and I came up with a third way that is also iOS 13 compatible, and only uses one `PreferenceKey` to help set the background color on the headers. This also allows unlimited columns. I think this is the simplest way of the bunch:

```
struct TableView: View {
    
    let headers: [String]
    let tableData: [String:[String]]
    let dataAlignment: [String:HorizontalAlignment]
    let headerColor: Color
    
    @State var headerHeight: CGFloat = 30
    
    init(headers: [String], headerColor: Color = Color.clear, columnData: [[String]], alignment: [HorizontalAlignment]) {
        self.headers = headers
        self.headerColor = headerColor
        if headers.count == columnData.count,
           headers.count == alignment.count {
            var data: [String:[String]] = [:]
            var align: [String:HorizontalAlignment] = [:]
            for i in 0..<headers.count {
                let key = headers[i]
                let value = columnData[i]
                data[key] = value
                align[key] = alignment[i]
            }
            dataAlignment = align
            tableData = data
        } else {
            tableData = [:]
            dataAlignment = [:]
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(headers, id: \.self) { header in
                    VStack {
                        Text(header)
                            .padding()
                            .background( GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Color.clear.preference(
                                    key: HeaderHeightPrefKey.self,
                                    value: geometry.size.height)
                            })
                        VStack(alignment: dataAlignment[header] ?? .center) {
                            ForEach(tableData[header] ?? [], id: \.self) { entry in
                                Text(entry)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(
                VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(headerColor)
                    .frame(height: headerHeight, alignment: .top)
                    Spacer()
                }
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(HeaderHeightPrefKey.self) {
                headerHeight = max($0,headerHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}
private extension TableView {
    struct HeaderHeightPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
        static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                           nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
    TableView(headers: ["Name", "Balance", "Currency"], headerColor: Color(uiColor: .systemGray5), columnData: [
        ["John", "Jennifer", "Jo", "Jill"],
        ["300", "53000", "30", "530000"],
        ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"]
    ], alignment: [.center, .trailing, .center])
```

and produces this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for both solutions! I never read anything at all regarding pref keys nor how they work, so Im gonna need to do some research to actually understand 100% whats going on here. For whatever reason I thought there was an easier way to align views to one another, but I guess this is it. As for grids, yeah I thought of those, Ill see if I can convince my team to drop iOS 13 on the next release, but we do support it as of now so thats a bummer. Anyhow, seriously appreciate the time you took to craft not one but two solutions. Thank you so so much! This is far easier on UIKIT, right?

Comment: Yes and no. It is more rigid on UIKit. With SwiftUI, you have to allow for fluidity of the views. Except for something like this with the iOS 13 restriction, SwiftUI is easier. You don't have to manage the constraints. You get yourself into trouble when you try to treat SwiftUI like UIKit and constraints as it behaves completely differently. And actually, it didn't take too long. This is pretty standard stuff; very little can't be learned about a view with a pref key.

Comment: Done! If I could, Id pick both your answer as well as Robs, they were truly both amazing. Thank you :).

Comment: Rob literally writes books, so definitely look at his.

Comment: I couldn't leave it alone. I posted a third way.

Comment: Alignment does not work as expected. I use Text().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: alignment) for each text element to correct it. I get the alignment information like this: let align = Alignment(horizontal: dataAlignment[header] ?? .center, vertical: .top)

Answer (score 4):

I see that Yrb posted a similar answer before me, but I'm going to post this anyway as my solution is a bit more modular/composable than theirs.

---

You want this layout:

[image: table with columns sized to fit content]

We're going to implement an API so that we can get your layout with this code for the table view:

```swift
enum ColumnId: Hashable {
    case name
    case balance
    case currency
}

struct TableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WidthPreferenceDomain {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Text("Name")
                        .widthPreference(ColumnId.name)
                    Text("Balance")
                        .widthPreference(ColumnId.balance)
                    Text("Currency")
                        .widthPreference(ColumnId.currency)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                .padding(12)
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9332349896, green: 0.9333916306, blue: 0.9332130551, alpha: 1)))
                ForEach(0 ..< 4) { _ in
                    RowView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above:

- I've defined a `ColumnId` type to identify each table column.
- I've inserted a `WidthPreferenceDomain` container view, which we will implement below.
- I've added a `widthPreference` modifier to each table row, which we will implement below.

We also need to use the `widthPreference` modifier in `RowView` like this:

```swift
struct RowView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("John")
                .widthPreference(ColumnId.name)
            Text("$5300")
                .widthPreference(ColumnId.balance)
            Text("EUR")
                .widthPreference(ColumnId.currency)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(12)
    }
}
```

I've placed the full code for this answer in [a gist for easy copying](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/260e019f307dfcb55f00e40a227a4225).

So, how do we implement `WidthPreferenceDomain` and `widthPreference`?

We need to measure the width of all the items in the Name column, including the Name title itself, so that we can then set all of the Name column's items to have the same width. We need to repeat the procedure for the Balance and Currency columns.

To measure the items, we can use `GeometryReader`. Because `GeometryReader` is a greedy view that expands to fill as much space as its parent offers, we don't want to wrap any table items in a `GeometryReader`. Instead, we want to put a `GeometryReader` in a `background` on each table item. A `background` view is given the same frame as its parent.

To collect the measured widths, we can use a “preference“ by defining a type conforming to the `PreferenceKey` protocol. Since we want to  collect the widths of all the columns, we'll store the widths in a `Dictionary`, keyed by a column id. To merge two widths for the same column, we take the maximum of the widths, so that each column expands to fit all its items.

```swift
fileprivate struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [AnyHashable: CGFloat] { [:] }

    static func reduce(value: inout [AnyHashable : CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [AnyHashable : CGFloat]) {
        value.merge(nextValue(), uniquingKeysWith: { max($0, $1) })
    }
}
```

To distribute the collected widths back down to the table items, we can use the “environment” by defining a type conforming to the `EnvironmentKey` protocol. `EnvironmentKey` only has one requirement, a `static var defaultValue` property, which matches the `PreferenceKey`'s `defaultValue` property, so we can re-use the `WidthPreferenceKey` type we already defined:

```swift
extension WidthPreferenceKey: EnvironmentKey { }
```

To use the environment, we also need to add a property to `EnvironmentValues`:

```swift
extension EnvironmentValues {
    fileprivate var widthPreference: WidthPreferenceKey.Value {
        get { self[WidthPreferenceKey.self] }
        set { self[WidthPreferenceKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now we can define the `widthPreference` modifier:

```swift
extension View {
    public func widthPreference<Domain: Hashable>(_ key: Domain) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(WidthPreferenceModifier(key: key))
    }
}

fileprivate struct WidthPreferenceModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.widthPreference) var widthPreference
    var key: AnyHashable

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: [key: proxy.size.width])
            })
            .frame(width: widthPreference[key])
    }
}
```

This modifier measures the modified view's width using a background `GeometryReader` and stores it in the preference. It also sets the view's width, **if** the `widthPreference` from the environment has a width for it. Note that `widthPreference[key]` will be `nil` on the first layout pass, but that's okay, because `frame(width: nil)` is an [“inert” modifier](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/?time=2306); it has no effect.

And now we can implement `WidthPreferenceDomain`. It needs to receive the preference and store it in the environment:

```swift
public struct WidthPreferenceDomain<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var widthPreference: WidthPreferenceKey.Value = [:]
    private var content: Content

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    public var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(\.widthPreference, widthPreference)
            .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { widthPreference = $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, honestly I didnt expect people to actually recreate my layout from scratch to help me out, thank you SO much for that as well as the thorough explanation. 

Honestly, I'm just starting and have never read anything at all regarding preference keys or how they work, so it does seem a little bit daunting to be honest! But I did run your code in a fresh project and the end result is exactly what Im after, so I guess I have a ton of reading/learning to do to fully grasp whats going on here. This layout is far more easier in UIKit, right? Anyhow, thanks so much! Ill read on pref keys now!

Comment: I didn't recreate your layout from scratch—I copied and pasted your code into a fresh project, then modified it. Good job including a complete, working sample in your question! — There's really not a lot of official documentation from Apple about SwiftUI preferences. [SwiftUI-Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/) is a gold mine though for advanced SwiftUI. — With UIKit's layout constraints, it's easy to make disparate views have matching widths. SwiftUI has yet to give us real control over its layout system.