# Custom grid in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need some help building this UI. what I want is to make a this grid [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm6eK.png)

What I have tried so fare is this, but the padding between Sets, reps, rest.

```
struct ProgramContainer: View {
var weight: String = "Weight"
@State var value = ""

private var columns: [GridItem] = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: 40), spacing: 40),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 1, maximum: 40), spacing: 40),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 1, maximum: 40), spacing: 40),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 1, maximum: 40), spacing: 40)
]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("name")
                .font(.title3).bold()
            Divider()
            LazyVGrid(
                columns: columns,
                alignment: .leading,
                spacing: 20,
                pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders, .sectionFooters]
            ) {
                Section {
                    ForEach(0...11, id: \.self) {index in
                        TextField("0", text: $value)
                    }
                } header: {
                    HStack(spacing: 40, content: {
                        Text(weight)
                        Text("Reps")
                        Text("Sets")
                        Text("Rest")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and it looks like this:
[image: 2]

Comment: How could be a Custom Grid using LazyVGrid undercover?! Custom means you should build Grid from zero. But your codes show the use case of LazyVGrid inside a project!

Comment: I though you could use that to build a custom grid....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You haven't asked a question. What do you want your grid to look like?

Comment: thanks for you comment, but I have already attached a picture of how my grid should look.

Comment: @FrederikHjorth - this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853681/swiftui-how-to-vertically-align-a-text-view-with-another-text-view-to-make-som

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if you use a LazyVGrid with the same number of columns (GridItems) for the Section header then it is easier to align the header and the items.

Workout Item:

```
struct Workout: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let weight: Int
let sets: Int
let reps: Int
let rest: Int
```

}

HeaderView:

```
struct WorkoutHeaderView: View {
private let labels = ["Weight", "Set", "Reps", "Rest"]
private let gridItems: [GridItem] = [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]

var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}
```

}

ProgramContainer:

```
struct ProgramContainer: View {
@State private var workoutData: [Workout] = [
    .init(weight: 100, sets: 3, reps: 12, rest: 1),
    .init(weight: 120, sets: 3, reps: 10, rest: 2)
]
private let gridItems: [GridItem] = [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Label")
            Divider()
        }
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 10) {
            Section(header: WorkoutHeaderView()) {
                ForEach(workoutData) { value in
                    Text("\(value.weight)")
                    Text("\(value.sets)")
                    Text("\(value.reps)")
                    Text("\(value.rest)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
            .frame(maxHeight: 150)
    }
    .padding()
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .opacity(0.5)
    )
    .padding()
}
```

}

[Layout Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyc0C.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response helped me a lot, do you know if it is possible to make a grid view with textfield where you can edit them one by one?